# How to convolve 1xW and reduce width only?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, dimensionality-reduction

Given a volume `[2, 2W, C]`, after applying pooling with 2x2 window and stride 2, I'm now left with `[1, W, C]` (height = 1px, width = half what it was before, channels = stays the same).

What I want to do now is apply a convolution op with the sole purpose of reducing that width dimension. Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes... just set both the kernel size and stride in height dimension to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible (though because it's unusual, the solution is a bit hackish).

**Conceptually**, there's no issue here.  This is frequently done in the depth/channel dimension rather than width, where people usually call it a 1x1 convolution.  Again the sole purpose is dimensionality reduction.  A nice blog post about it is http://iamaaditya.github.io/2016/03/one-by-one-convolution/ (to be clear, I am not the author of that blog).  That is, a typical 1x1 conv layer is really a bank of `D2` filters of size `1x1xD`, and dimensionality reduction is achieved by `D2 < D`.  Here you want the same thing but in width: `1xWx1` filter size, `W2` times. Conceptually then, that's it; it should be easy.

**Practically** of course, this is not so easy, as in CNNs convention treats width and depth differently: one convolves over width, but filters always operate on the full depth stack; making a 1x1 convolution easy in depth, but tricky in width.  You have at least two options in `tensorflow`:

1. Use a full width filter with no zero padding

   ```
   tf.nn.conv2d(input,filter,strides,padding="VALID",...)
   ```

   such that `filter_width = W` (as in `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`).  You then make several of these, which gets you the output information you want.  **Pro**: This considers the full width of the stack, so serves as a dimensionality reduction in the equivalent sense as a typical (depth) 1x1 convolution.  **Con**: This moves your width information to the depth stack (you get width of 1 for each filter, so your "reduced" dimension is not in the width, but in the depth. That's almost certainly not desirable.  You could `tf.reshape` your way out of it, but yuck.
2. Use strides to sort of accomplish this

   ```
   tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, [1,1,2,1],padding="VALID",...)
   ```

   where `strides` has been specified as `[1,1,2,1]` and you specify `filter` where `filter_width = 2`.  This will reduce your width dimension by 2 (or 3 or any other factor that divides your width evenly), using a stride that matches your filter width (and critically zero padding that will be in effect 0).  **Pro** this is clean and produces the data sizes you want without the reshaping annoyance above.  **Con** this isn't doing a 1x1 convolution / dimension reduction in the usual sense.  It is reducing dimension pairwise (every two adjacent dimensions are becoming one), **not** mixing all dimensions together.  This is not a good dimensionality reduction method, so you might lose a lot of signal.  Probably you should try this one because it's much cleaner, but be forewarned about that issue.